# line 25, in <module> sigs = subprocess.check_output('listdlls' + process_name, text = True).decode("utf-8")

Tags: python, python-3.x

можете пожалуйста подсказать, в чем ошибка ?

```
import subprocess
import zlib
import time
import os

process_name = "game.exe" # название игры (процесса)
signatures = "" # изначальные сигнатуры
mode = 1 # режим 
v = "1.0.0.BETA" # версия проги
scan_delay = 10 # промежуток времени проверки сигнатур

def crc(fileName):
    prev = 0
    for eachline in open(fileName, "rb"):
        prev = zlib.crc32(eachline, prev)
    return "%X"%(prev & 0xFFFFFFFF)

# имплементация
sigs_path = "./sigs/" + process_name + "_sigs.txt"
sigs_local_path = "./sig.txt"

if mode:

    # создание сигнатур процесса
    sigs = subprocess.check_output('listdlls' + process_name, text = True).decode("utf-8")

    f.write( sigs )
    f.close()

    print("Signatures of process " + process_name + " created")

    # Протекция по сигнатурам
    f = open(sigs_local_path, 'w')
    f.write( sigs )
    f.close()

    while True:
        print("Scanning the game...")

        sig = subprocess.check_output("listdlls " + process_name, text = True).decode("utf-8")
        f = open(sigs_local_path, 'w')
        f.write( sigs )
        f.close()


        if (crc(sigs_path) == crc(sigs_local_path)):
            # Сигнатуры одинаковые
            print("signatures matched, continue... ")
            time.sleep(scan_delay);
            continue;
        else:
            # Сигнатуры не одинаковые
            print("Signatures didnt match, close the game")
            os.system("taskkill /IM " + process_name + "/F")
            break;

print("Anticheat v "/v/" has stopped working")
```

---

**Ошибка:**

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dima\Desktop\Sublime Text 3\projects(scripts)\anticheat.py", line 25, in <module>
    sigs = subprocess.check_output('listdlls ' + process_name, text = True).decode("utf-8")
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\Dima\Desktop\Sublime Text 3\projects(scripts)\anticheat.py"]
[dir: C:\Users\Dima\Desktop\Sublime Text 3\projects(scripts)]
[path: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]`
```

Comment: Укажите тип ошибки в тексте вопроса

Comment: Пропущен пробел. В строке 25 используйте: `subprocess.check_output('listdlls ' + process_name, text = True)`

Comment: Sergey, уже пробовал